# PHP: Assign array to variable

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

> i've tried a lot of things to achieve this but none of them seem to
>   work. **Im using PHP 7.4**
>
> Let's say i have this:
>
> ```
> $othervar = array();
> $var = array(1, 2, 3);
> $othervar = $var;
> ```
>
> THIS doesn't work for me, *var_dump($othervar)* returns
>
> ```
> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "Array" }
> ```
>
> I've tried using array_push, i DON'T WANT to use array_merge because i
>   need to assign two arrays to one variable. This is what i need to do:
>
> ```
> $variable = array();
> $variable["type1"] = $data; //Array 1
> $variable["type2"] = $otherData; //Array 2
> ```
>
> This doesn't work either.

Barmar showed me [here](https://ideone.com/96ynWx)  that this works so i must be doing it wrong somewhere else.

I'll explan the whole code:

To login to my webpage, i send a request trough AJAX request with jQuery.

```
function SendData(data, btn, actionOnSuccess, shouldReplace = false, elementToReplace = "", getServerData = true, htmlData = "") {
    if (!loading)
    {
        ToggleLoading();
        data.push({name: "action", value: $(btn).data("action")});
        data.push({name: "attr", value: JSON.stringify($(btn).data("attr"))});
        $.post("SendRequest.php", data)
            .done(function (r) {
                if (!r.success)
                    //ajax sent and received but it has an error
                else
                    //ajax sent and it was successfull
            })
            .fail(function () {
                //ajax call failed
            });
    }
    else {
        //This determines if some request is already executing or not.
    }
}
```

"action" and "attr" are encrypted values that i send to reference some actions on the system (i'll show more here):

The code goes from AJAX to **SendRequest.php** where it executes an action let's say, login.

The first lines of SendRequest.php are:

```
    require "Functions.php";

    $apiAction = Decrypt($_POST["action"]); //Action
    $actionData = json_decode(Decrypt($_POST["attr"])); //Attr
    $finalPost = $_POST;
    foreach ($actionData as $key => $value) { $finalPost[$key] = $value; }

    $finalPost["loggedin_ip"] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $result = APICall($apiAction, $finalPost);
```

Then, this is what i want to achieve to communicate with my API:

```
function APICall($option, $data = array())
{
    session_start();
    $post = array("uData" => ArrayToAPI($_SESSION), "uPost" => ArrayToAPI($data));

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://apiurl?" . $option); //option is the ACTION to perform on API (let's say "login") it is an encrypted word on a data-attr atribute on every form/button that creates a communication with API.
    $returned = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    $newData = json_decode($returned, true);
    return $newData;
}

function ArrayToAPI($array)
{
    $toApiData = array();
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        if (is_array($value))
            $toApiData[$key] = ArrayToAPI($value);
        else
            $toApiData[$key] = Encrypt($value);
    }
    return $toApiData;
}
```

This is what i have on API side:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($_POST);
$result = ob_get_clean();
$api->EndRequest(false, array("errorDesc" => "a - " . $result));

function EndRequest(bool $task_completed, array $data = array())
{
    $jsonData = array();
    $jsonData['success'] = $task_completed;
    $jsonData['data'] = $data;
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($jsonData, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    exit;
}
```

This ALWAYS returns

```
array(2) { ["uData"]=> string(5) "Array" ["uPost"]=> string(5) "Array" }
```

I hope im more clear now, thanks.

Comment: What returns `array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "Array" }`? var_dump($othervar) says `array(3) ...` like $var is declared.

Comment: You must be doing something different than you posted. You only get the string `Array` when you do something that converts an array to a string.

Comment: Assigning variables doesn't do that.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: do you want a multidimensional array as a result?

Comment: @MarkusZeller yes, var_dump returns that.

Comment: @Barmar no, even if you do the first example i showed var_dump throws that result

Comment: @KunalRaut Exactly, but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: @DEFALTUSER No it doesn't: https://ideone.com/96ynWx

Comment: @Barmar I'll edit my question to show you the whole code

Comment: @Barmar it's edited :D

Comment: I suspect the problem is with `Decrypt()`.

Comment: @Barmar nope, even if i don't encrypt and decrypt data happens the same thing

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);` doesn't support multi-level arrays. Your array values (which the keys are pointing to) are cast to string, which ends up as `Array`. Use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));` instead to "properly" serialize multidimensional arrays in a post request ("properly" as there are many ways to do just that, but it matches the expected PHP version - with `[]`).

Comment: @MatsLindh My god thank you!, you know.. i've been trying to solve this problem for more than 5 days. How do i mark that as an answer?

Comment: @DEFALTUSER I've added it as a proper answer, feel free to accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the request being sent out from your code because of this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` doesn't support multi-level arrays. Your array values (which the keys are pointing to) are cast to string, which ends up as `Array`. Use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
```

.. instead to "properly" serialize multidimensional arrays in a post request ("properly" as there are many ways to do just that, but it matches the expected PHP format - with `[]` to denote arrays).